# Highcharts windbarb out-of-memory crash

Tags: reactjs, memory, highcharts

I'm trying to use the modules windbarb in a react project.
On render, chrome pauses the process with a "paused before potential out-of-memory crash" highlighting line 135 in the windbarb.js file.

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import WindBarbs from 'highcharts/modules/windbarb'

WindBarbs(Highcharts)

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lineData: [
                [1569243600000, 12.5],
                [1569247200000, 12.2]
            ],
            windData: [
                [1569243600000, 29.6],
                [1569247200000, 26.5]
            ],
            highcharts: Highcharts
        }
    }
    render(){
        let options = {
            series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                type: 'line',
                data: this.state.lineData
            }, {
                name: 'Wind direction',
                type: 'windbarb',
                data: this.state.windData
            }]
        }
        return(
            <HighchartsReact
                highcharts={this.state.highcharts}
                options={options}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is related to your data. First elements from the data array by default are used as `values` for `windbard` series which causes very complex svg rendering. As a solution you can use `keys` option.

```
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    data: [
        [1569243600000, 12.5],
        [1569247200000, 12.2]
    ]
}, {
    type: 'windbarb',
    keys: ['x', 'value'],
    data: [
        [1569243600000, 29.6],
        [1569247200000, 26.5]
    ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0k8vmzfd/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.windbarb.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.windbarb.keys